# How to handle ENTER key as a mouse click or a tap on the mapview

Tags: android, maps

I'm working on a android map based application . Everything is ok in touch mode. But in keyboard devices i have a funny problem !
in touch mode , when i click on new layers which generated by the app on the map , a baloon appear which shows some information ! but in keyboard mode i cant do that !
I want to know that is there any way to handle the ENTER key as Left mouse key click or a tap!